# "Error in .People/Component class PeopleComponent - inline template:93:8 caused by: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'"

Tags: angularjs, angular

i am able to fetch data from the database which is showing in my network tab alright but my app gives an error when i am trying to display the fetched data in my table. The error display ""Error in .People/Component class PeopleComponent - inline template:93:8 caused by: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'""

```
//component

    export class PeopleComponent {


        People: Peoples[] = [];


        constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private router: Router) {

                this.httpService.getPeople()
                .subscribe(data => {
                        this.People = data;
                    }
                );

        }
    //service
     getPeople() {
          let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token });
          let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get('http://example.com', options)
          .map((response:Response) => response.json());
      }


    //table

    <table  class="table" id="table"  >

      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Group</th>
        <th>Country</th>



      </tr>

      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let people of People" >
          <td>{{people.group}}</td>
          <td>{{people.country}}</td>

          </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

// updated table

    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let key of People | keys; let i = index" >
          <td>{{i + 1}}</td>

        <td>{{People[key].first_name + " " + People[key].last_name}}</td>
          <td>{{People[key].group}}</td>
          <td>{{People[[key].country}}</td>


 </tr>

      </tbody>
```

//pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value) : any {
        if(value) {
            return Object.keys(value)
        }
    }
}
```

//image
[image: how the table looks now]

Comment: You still get the same error message?

Comment: this is how the table looks @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*ngFor` only supports iterating an array, not arbitrary classes.

You can use a pipe for example like the following to get an array of keys you can iterate:

```
@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value) : any {
    if(value) {
      return Object.keys(value)
    }
  }
}
```

```
 <tr *ngFor="let key of People | keys " >
      <td>{{People[key].group}}</td>
      <td>{{People[key].country}}</td>

      </tr>

  </tbody>
```

Comment: i have updated the question with your solution but in the console it raises an error " Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keys' could not be found ("

  <tbody>
    <tr [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let key of People | keys; let i = index" >
      <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
      <!--td><input  #{{"): PeopleComponent@93:8 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'keys' could not be found ("
"

Comment: You need to add the pipe to `@NgModule({declarations: [KeysPipe]})`

Comment: the table shows now but it's empty and it raises the error "EXCEPTION: Error in ./PeopleComponent class PeopleComponent - inline template:101:62 caused by: self.parent.context.people is undefined"

Comment: looking at the updated table in the question, when i hover over the attributes, group and country,  it says unresolved variable

Comment: Sorry, I got confused by your naming convention. `People` is supposed to be an array and should just work. It looks like in `this.People = data;`, `data` is just not an array like you expect. Try adding `<div>{{People}}</div>` and check the output and post it here if possible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but after trying <div>{{People}}</div>   get the same error "Error in ./PeopleComponent class PeopleComponent - inline template:95:33 caused by: self.parent.context.client is undefined  main.bundle.js:48946:9
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.parent.context.client is undefined"